# Add NPM installed script

Tags: reactjs, npm

This is more than likely a very stupid and silly question but I just can't seem to find an answer that seems to work for me. Creating a react website and found this neat little [npm package](https://ranbuch.github.io/accessibility/) for accessibility. I have installed the npm but I just can't seem to get my head around the instructions on where to add the script and windows listener?
Example of my component in my Home.jsx file, where and how do I add what the documentation above says to add?

```
 class Home extends Component {

  render() {
    return (

        <div>

          **CONTENT**
        </div>
 );
  }
}

export default Home
```

For anyone not wanting to click on the link the instructions they give are
install package:

npm install accessibility

> include script:
>
> script type="text/javascript"
>   src="node_modules/accessibility/dist/accessibility.min.js">/script>
>
> initialize component
>
> window.addEventListener('load', function() {
>       new Accessibility(); }, false);

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you used CRA (create-react-app) both of those have to be added inside the `index.html`. Just paste these

```html
<script type="text/javascript" 
  src="node_modules/accessibility/dist/accessibility.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     window.addEventListener('load', function() {
       new Accessibility();
     }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Added that into the head of my index.html. Nothing has happened. Must I call it or anything in the likes of my App.js or other components like home.js?

Comment: Well the script won't do the magic by itself, you have to use it after...